# SQLite to Oracle 0 records showing up

Tags: java, oracle, inner-join, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hey all I have the query below that I wrote when I was using SQLite:

```
SELECT 
    ad.ID,ad.Script_Name,ad.Current_Status,
    ad.Issues_found_during_run,ad.Testers,
    ad.Run_Date,ad.Tools,u.fTag,u.role,u.avatar 
FROM 
    allData ad 
INNER JOIN 
    users u 
ON 
    u.fTag = ad.lastUserWhoUpdated 
GROUP BY 
    ad.ID 
ORDER BY 
    ad.ID ASC
```

That produces the 6 records I would imagine would come up with that query.

However, I have since moved to using Oracle database. This is my information on the Oracle server I am using:

> Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

So when I convert the SQLite data to Oracle and run the same query with just a modification for the **GROUP BY** since it seems Oracle wants all the names that are in the SELECT statement and not just the one I need to group by:

```
SELECT 
    ad.ID,ad.Script_Name,ad.Current_Status,
    ad.Issues_found_during_run,ad.Testers,
    ad.Run_Date,ad.Tools,u.fTag,u.role,u.avatar 
FROM 
    allData ad 
INNER JOIN 
    users u 
ON 
    u.fTag = ad.lastUserWhoUpdated 
GROUP BY 
    ad.ID,ad.Script_Name,ad.Current_Status,ad.Issues_found_during_run,ad.Testers,ad.Run_Date,ad.Tools,u.fTag,u.role,u.avatar 
ORDER BY 
    ad.ID ASC;
```

That above produces 0 records when ran in SQL Developer. So, what would Oracle need me to do in order to fix this so it pulls the 6 records as did the SQLite version?

Comment: The query you wrote when you were using SQLite uses a *feature* (or a bug) of SQLite that allows you to select non aggregated columns besides the 1 that you group by. I've seen this *feature* in action and I remember that the returned additional columns were taken from the last row of each group (although this is not guaranteed). If this is what you need you must provide sample data and expected results so to find a way to distinguish this last row of each group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT 
ad.ID,MAX(ad.Script_Name), MAX(ad.Current_Status),
MAX(ad.Issues_found_during_run), MAX(ad.Testers),
MAX(ad.Run_Date), MAX(ad.Tools), MAX(u.fTag),MAX(u.role),MAX(u.avatar) 
FROM 
 allData ad 
INNER JOIN 
 users u 
ON 
 u.fTag = ad.lastUserWhoUpdated 
GROUP BY 
ad.ID
ORDER BY 
ad.ID ASC;
```

More on Aggregrate functions here:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm

Comment: Running that in SQL Developer also returns 0 records.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense (to me, at least). There's no `WHERE` clause which would restrict number of rows returned. `GROUP BY` certainly doesn't have to do anything with that. The only *suspicious* thing is

```
on u.fTag = ad.lastUserWhoUpdated
```

which caused no rows to be retrieved.

Therefore:

- are you sure that there are matching values in those two tables?
- check those two columns' datatypes, especially if one (or both) are `CHAR` (I mean *CHAR*, not `VARCHAR2`) which right-pads values with *blanks* up to the whole column size, so you might try with

  ```
  on trim(u.fTag) = trim(ad.lastUserWhoUpdated)
  ```

  which has its drawbacks (index won't be used, unless it is a function-based) so - if it turns out that it is the case, modify datatype to `VARCHAR2`.